# How to not stop surface view while taking picture

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I would like to take multi picture and i'm using these codes. But it makes the screen freeze (after stop and start preview) in a short time and make the users uncomfortable.
How can I resolve this problem. Thanks for your attention.

```
PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            cpreview.mCamera.startPreview();
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            /*try {

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                        "/sdcard/camtest/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }*/

        }
    };
```

If there is no way, I'm thinking of recording video and then convert it to images ( though it waste more time).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the latest phones like nexus 4, samsung galaxy s5 etc support a camera parameter called "zsl" (Zero shutter lag).

In regular image capture sequence, camera HAL stops preview and takes picture. But when this parameter is set, preview will not be stopped while capturing picture. And also image will be captured comparatively faster. Since preview will not be stopped you will not see above problem and also you don't have to call start preview in picture callback.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to make it seamless(although the pause is getting smaller on newer phones). The camera is simply too busy while capturing the image to feed previews.

Video is a good alternative, but only if you're willing to sacrifice a lot of image quality. If you're concerned about wasted space, you can delete the original video after extracting your images.